# Health Checks UI display results in categories

Tags: asp.net-core

I have implemented [Xabaril's Healthchecks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) in a simple `.NET Core 3.0` API project. I am checking several URLs and SQL servers as a test and I successfully display the results in the HealthCheckUI. They all appear under the one 'category' that I defined in `appSettings`. Now, [in the documentation](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/doc/images/ui-home.png) you can see that you could have multiple of these categories, but it seems that this is meant to be used only when you display results from different sources.

What I want to do is have my API project check say 3 URIs and display them under a "Web" category, and then check 3 SQL servers and display them under a "SQL" category.

From this [example here](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/samples/HealthChecks.Sample/Startup.cs) it seems that we can achieve the 2 different categories with this piece of code:

```
            app
            .UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = _ => true
            })
            .UseHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = _ => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
            })
```

However in the Startup class, when we add checks we do not specify to which API endpoint they should be reported to so that we can categorize them:
`services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck...`

Am I missing something or this UI client is not meant to be used like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working in a Net Core 3.1 project using tags.

For example if you wanted a Database and API section in the Spa UI:

In **ConfigureServices** method of **Startup.cs**

```c#
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddSqlServer("ConnectionString", name: "Application Db", tags: new[] { "database" })
    .AddHangfire(options => { options.MinimumAvailableServers = 1; }, "Hangfire Db", tags: new[] { "database" })
    .AddUrlGroup(new Uri("https://myapi.com/api/person"), HttpMethod.Get, "Person Endpoint", tags: new[] { "api" })
    .AddUrlGroup(new Uri("https://myapi.com/api/organisation"), HttpMethod.Get, "Org Endpoint", tags: new[] { "api" })
    .AddUrlGroup(new Uri("https://myapi.com/api/address"), HttpMethod.Get, "Address Endpoint", tags: new[] { "api" });
```

In **Configure** method of **Startup.cs**

```c#
config.MapHealthChecks("/health-check-database", new HealthCheckOptions
{
     Predicate = r => r.Tags.Contains("database"),
     ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
});

config.MapHealthChecks("/health-check-api", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    Predicate = r => r.Tags.Contains("api"),
    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
});
```

Then **appsettings.json** something like:

```json
"HealthChecksUI": {
"HealthChecks": [
  {
    "Name": "Database Health Checks",
    "Uri": "https://myapi.com/api/health-check-database"
  },
  {
    "Name": "API Health Checks",
    "Uri": "https://myapi.com/api/health-check-api"
  }
],
"Webhooks": [],
"EvaluationTimeinSeconds": 10,
"MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60
}
```